# Sort Django Rest API Endpoint Response by Date

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Let's say I have a response from a endpoint. I am using Django Rest Framework. Let's say this is what is returning from endpoint.

```
[
  {
    Name: "q4",
    Date: "2020-09-30T18:00:52+03:00",
    Url: "/test/test",
  },
  {
    Name: "q2",
    Date: "2020-10-01T13:32:21+03:00",
    Url: "/test",
  },
  {
    Name: "q1",
    Date: "2020-09-30T17:42:06+03:00",
    Url: "/xyz",
  },
  {
    Name: "q3",
    Date: "2020-09-30T13:04:23+03:00",
    Url: "...",
  },
  {
    Name: "q5",
    Date: "2020-10-01T13:04:45+03:00",
    Url: "...",
  },
]
```

**How am I going to change ordering of response by respecting to date and time like this?**

```
[
  {
    Name: "q3",
    Date: "2020-09-30T13:04:23+03:00",
    Url: "...",
  },
  {
    Name: "q1",
    Date: "2020-09-30T17:42:06+03:00",
    Url: "/xyz",
  },
  {
    Name: "q4",
    Date: "2020-09-30T18:00:52+03:00",
    Url: "/test/test",
  },
  {
    Name: "q5",
    Date: "2020-10-01T13:04:45+03:00",
    Url: "...",
  },
  {
    Name: "q2",
    Date: "2020-10-01T13:32:21+03:00",
    Url: "/test",
  }
]
```

Comment: add the corresponding view class/function

Comment: Could you please clarify your goal?

Is this a response that you queried from an API that was build using Django Rest Framework and you want to sort the items in the response?

Or are you building an API using the Rest Framework and want to sort the items in the response you are providing to clients?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use order_by in the queryset to order the results:

```
Model.objects.order_by('creation_time')
```

Check the [Queryset API reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) for more details